# unable to execute oracle data setup script from docker compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, cloud, oracle12c

I am trying to set up oracle data once my oracle container is up and running, below is my compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  oracle:
   image: absolutapps/oracle-12c-ee
   container_name: oracle-docker
  ports:
  - 8080:8080
  - 1521:1521
  environment:
    CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
    ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE: "true"
  volumes:
  - ./scripts/oracle-init.sh:/oracle-init.sh
```

oracle-init.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "### SETUP EXECUTION! ###"
sqlplus -s "system/oracle@localhost:1521/orcl /scripts/init-oracle.sql"
echo "### SETUP EXECUTED! ###"
```

init-oracle.sql :

`CREATE USER ot_consumer_tryout IDENTIFIED BY ot_consumer_tryout;`
Can anyone help me what is wrong with above snippets. My docker container getting started but sql script does not execute ,here is the log from terminal:

> oracle-docker | Running init scripts...
> oracle-docker | Init scripts in /oracle.init.d/: Ignoring /oracle.init.d/*
> oracle-docker |
> oracle-docker | Done with scripts we are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

Look at the volume you created

`- ./scripts/oracle-init.sh:/oracle-init.sh`

which means inside your container the file is in '/oracle-init.sh' but your
container might be expecting in a different location something with folder name `oracle.init.d` as per your container log.

`oracle-init.sh` is trying to run `/scripts/init-oracle.sql` , hope your image already has it otherwise you will have to mount it as well in compose file.